# Expected 'multiple' syntax before 'single' syntax

Tags: eslint

I am trying to import files like this but getting error: Expected 'multiple' syntax before 'single' syntax

```
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import { getModule } from 'vuex-module-decorators';
import { ApiException, IProduct, IProductCategory } from '@/services'; // error here
import { INavs } from '@/types';
```

Rule config:

```
'sort-imports': ['error', {
    'ignoreCase': false,
    'ignoreDeclarationSort': false,
    'ignoreMemberSort': false,
    'memberSyntaxSortOrder': ['none', 'all', 'multiple', 'single']
}]
```

Answer (score 16):

`import { ApiException, IProduct, IProductCategory } from '@/services';` is importing multiple (three) exports.

Both `import { getModule } from 'vuex-module-decorators';` and `import { INavs } from '@/types';` are only importing a single named export.

That error will go way if you move `import { ApiException, IProduct, IProductCategory }` up one line so it's above the single imports.
This is configured in your settings where it says `'memberSyntaxSortOrder': ['none', 'all', 'multiple', 'single']` because 'multiple' is listed before 'single'.

You can read more about it in the eslint documentation here https://eslint.org/docs/rules/sort-imports

Comment: This is the answer. And also, I disagree with how they implemented `single`. To me, anything that uses destructuring, whether it be for a single element `import { INavs }` or multiple elements `import { Component, Prop, Vue }`, should be "treated" by this rule as `multiple`. This helps distinguish it from _proper_ `single` imports, like `import React`. Otherwise, there is no way to distinguish between `import React` and `import { Vue }` because they are both treated as `single`.

Comment: Fully agree with the sentiment above, Joshua. Not that this changes much!

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this too looking for a CI solution for reordering multiple imports, since ESLint `--fix` only supports *multiple members on a single line*; i.e. autofixing unsupported when spread over multiple lines - e.g. from a low Prettier *printWidth* of ~80.

`eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort` works great, fixed the errors after amending config from the [docs](https://github.com/lydell/eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort#usage):

> Make sure *not* to use other sorting rules at the same time:
>
> - [sort-imports]
> - [import/order]

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue I'll recommend modifying your `.eslintrc.json` setting

```json
    "sort-imports": ["error", {
        "ignoreCase": false,
        "ignoreDeclarationSort": false,
        "ignoreMemberSort": false,
        "memberSyntaxSortOrder": ["none", "all", "multiple", "single"],
        "allowSeparatedGroups": false // <-- Change this to true
      }],
```

Which prevents you from reordering local imports and third party imports that are in different groups but violate the `memberSyntaxSortOrder`  as earlier suggested